# SBT, difference between <<= and :=

Tags: scala, sbt

These methods [are not described in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.TaskKey). I mostly use `:=` in my .sbt files, but sometimes, because of reasons I don't yet understand, tasks that I assign with `:=` don't work (meaning tasks don't produce side-effects and don't return anything), and work with `<<=`. So what's the difference between `<<=` and `:=`?

Edit:

My example below runs a cleaning task, and when it is done (`doFinally`), runs two other tasks concurrently.

```
gae_prep_war := {
  val after = Def.task {
    (gae_copyJars).value; (compile in Compile).value;
  }
  (gae_clean, after) {
    (clean, task) => clean doFinally task
  }
}
```

As it is now it does not work, no error, but no effect or output either; if I change `:=` to `<<=` it works. My SBT version is 0.13.0 and using Scala 2.10.2.

Edit2:

I have discovered that `:=` works if I simply append `.value` to the outer expression:

```
gae_prep_war := {
  val after = Def.task {
    (gae_copyJars).value; (compile in Compile).value;
  }
  (gae_clean, after) {
    (clean, task) => clean doFinally task
  }
}.value

  ^
```

But I still don't quite understand why...

Comment: If you show us your attempt to use `:=` with a task, I imagine we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @SethTisue I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: `:=` expects the thing on its right hand side to use `.value` to actually evaluate any tasks or settings that it mentions. In your case, everything between the outer `{ }` merely describes a task; `.value` actually runs it, and the result becomes the result of `gae_prep_war`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sbt 0.13, `<<=` is obsolete. It was used when a task definition introduced dependencies on other tasks - it allows you to pull in the results of those other tasks. Here are the 0.12.4 docs on it: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values

In 0.13 you can just use `:=` always, so you can see how the docs change in 0.13 here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values

So for 0.13 and beyond it's safe to forget about `<<=`.

If the docs links above don't make sense, it may help to go back to the start of the getting started guide and read in order to get the background.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using sbt 0.13.0 and my code works only with `<<=`. I have added an example.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis It looks like the information Havoc provided in this answer is correct. As long as you call `.value`, the `:=` syntax should work and appears to be the way to go in 0.13. Did this not answer your question?